# How to change content type in a site page on list details

Tags: sharepoint-online, content

I have created a web page showing a SharePoint list. I am trying to modify the content type of the details pane that is appearing on the right part of the screen when user clicks on the circled i.
I thought I would just have to add the content type ID in the html address but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Does somebody has an idea how to proceed?

Many thanks in advance
Nico

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume you use the SharePoint Online modern page list web part.

Unfortunately, we cannot edit the content type in the list web part in modern page by default.

As a workaround, I suggest you click "see all" to direct to list and change the item content type.